# Read entire msgpack file with Rust

Tags: rust, serde, msgpack

How do I read an entire msgpack file and convert it to a json file with rust?

I have tried the following:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter, Write};
use std::fs;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let file_path = "./src/foo.msgpack";
    let reader = BufReader::new(File::open(file_path).unwrap());
    let writer = BufWriter::new(File::create("./src/results.json").unwrap());

    let mut deserializer = rmp_serde::Deserializer::from_read(reader);

    // let mut serializer = serde_json::Serializer::new(io::stdout());
    let mut serializer = serde_json::Serializer::pretty(writer);

    serde_transcode::transcode(&mut deserializer, &mut serializer).unwrap();
    serializer.into_inner().flush().unwrap();

    Ok(())
}
```

This reads the first line out of the msgpack file, and no more.

Other libraries such as serde_json can turn a deserializer into an iterator (https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/de/struct.Deserializer.html#method.into_iter) which seems to be what I want, but `rmp_serde` doesn't do this - and I'm too much of a rust newbie to figure this out myself.

Thanks!

Comment: well, like you did, without your test input it's impossible to check if the error is on your side or on the serde_transcode side, however note that json can't represent all values of msgpack

Comment: Cheers @Stargateur, unfortunately I can't share my input file for compliance reasons. I can successfully deserialize the entire file into JSON with Python though - hence why I'm pretty convinced it's a code issue.

Comment: Your input file contains one line per object, and your code reads only the first object, correct?

Comment: @Cerberus yup, that's correct. I've tried reading line by line as bytes with `ByteLines`, but again I get the first line perfect, and then just "values" in the subsequent lines.

Comment: @Stuart Well, you could make a test input you can share. Just some dummy data would do, as long as it reproduces the problem. (`rq` might help with some quick conversions.)

Comment: Shucks, think I might've just figured out the problem - thanks @Caesar for prompting me. The encoding type of my msgpack files seems to be "data". when I generate a msgpack file with encoding "Non ISO extended ASCII text, no line terminators", my rust program works fine.

Comment: This feels like more an issue of how to open a file with a different encoding in rust than a serialization/deserialization problem!

Comment: that clearly the contrary it's you using a non standard encoding format of msgpack. Maybe try using https://docs.rs/rmp-serde/1.1.1/rmp_serde/config/struct.HumanReadableConfig.html